Start Native address took my Ethereum instead of my Remix bot
After watching a youtube video on a certain ethereum bot I followed the instructions and somehow found that the money was sent to some start native address and wasn't being used by my bot. I was hoping there was a way I could get the ethereum out of this contract and back into my wallet.


There is not. Don't use others code, that is the worst thing to do.

Youtube videos are not safe for production level code. Remember that.
